# Use of pumping lemma for not regular languages. (Proof Verification)

Tags: pumping-lemma, check-my-answer

$L=\{w \in \{0,1,a\}^* | \#_0(w) = \#_1(w) \}$

We show that L is not regular by pumping lemma.

We choose w=$0^p 1^p a$

|w| = 2p+1

Now |xy| has to be $\leq p$

So x and y could only contain zeros. And $z=1^p a$

$xy^iz= 0^p 1^p a$

Now let i = 0

$xy^0z=0^{p-|y|} 1^p a$

Now hence $p-|y| \neq p$ this choice of i would lead to a word that is not in L. So we can not pump y and stay in the language.

So L is not regular.

I'm trying to learn the usage of the pumping lemma. Is my proof correct?

Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: "Now |xy| has to be ≤" what are x and y?

Comment: Pumping lemma states that w has to be split into xyz. So x the first part y the second and z the last part of w. Do I have to mention this in every proof for it?

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Comment: It's proof verification. I have asked for suggestions to improve my proof.

Answer (score 0):

Use your freedom to pick a string to work with. The string $0^p 1^p$ is all around nicer.

Assume $L = \{ w \in \{0, 1, a\}^* \colon \#_0 w = \#_1 w \}$ is regular, so it satisfies the pumping lemma. Let $p$ be the constant of the lemma, we know $p \ge 1$. Pick $w = 0^p 1^p$, so $\lvert w \rvert = 2 p \ge p$, by the lemma there is a division $w = x y z$ with $\lvert x y \rvert \le p$ and $y \ne \varepsilon$ so that for all $k \ge 0$ the string $x y^k z$ belongs to $L$.

What does the above tell you about $x, y, z$? Can you derive a contradiction by picking e.g. $k = 0$? You finish it off.

Comment: I have done the same so far.